# app academy ruby-test-first spec errors

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm new to programming and I'm currently learning on my own. I'm following first **[precourse](https://github.com/appacademy/test-first-ruby)** for App Academy.
I'm having tons of trouble trying to get the first spec to run on the first project 00_hello.

I'm working on a Windows 7 pc 64 bit and I haven't had much issues running Ruby on it till I had to use rspec.

I also have a VM running Mac OS X but I'm having similar issues on that too.

The current error I'm getting when I run 00_hello_spec is

> D:/1/spec/00_hello_spec.rb:105:in `<main>': undefined method`
>   describe' for main :Object (NoMethodError)

This is my first time using rspec, I really appreciate any help setting it up properly and getting it running.

Here is the content of `00_hello_spec.rb`:

```
require "00_hello"

describe "the hello function" do
  it "says hello" do
    hello.should == "Hello!"
  end
end

describe "the greet function" do
  it "says hello to someone" do
    greet("Alice").should == "Hello, Alice!"
  end

  it "says hello to someone else" do
    greet("Bob").should == "Hello, Bob!"
  end
end
```

Comment: it looks like rspec isn't getting loaded

Comment: I have rspec installed

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with those tests.

First run rspec -v that will tell you if RSPEC is working. 
Second change the 'require' line in the file to:

```
require "./hello"
```

As the default actually just gives you "hello" and sometimes it can't find the other file because of that. Both files need to be in the same folder for that to work.

If RSPEC is working and you have that line altered it should work. If it doesn't uninstall RSPEC and use a tutorial to re-install it.

Also a lastly when you run it in the terminal make sure you use

```
rspec hello_spec.rb
```

If you use the Ruby command it won't work.

Comment: If you make an edit suggestion for the question, you should provide a more descriptive summary explaining why you made the edit, such as *"add the code that the OP put in the comments"*. We don't see the comments in the edit review, and with no edit description, it looks like you're trying to answer or reply by editing the question.